# How to continue code execution after the exception is thrown in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

How to change this code to continue app execution after the Exception is thrown?

```
if (str is null || str == string.Empty)
{
    throw new Exception("Wrong str");
}
```

Comment: Where?  If you mean directly after the `if` then why are you throwing?  Typically you'd have a `try/catch` somewhere higher up the call stack that handles the exception.

Comment: Downvoting because this is not an appropriate use of `throw new Exception`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
                    try
                    {
                        if (str is null || str == string.Empty)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Wrong str");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception strException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(strException.Message);
                    }

                    //Continue......
```

Comment: Throwing to immediately catch like this is bad practice.  The code would be better served to have the `WriteLine` inside of the `if` and completely remove throwing the exception and catching it.

Comment: I am not of this opinion and I find the answer correct for the code provided as a sample without taking into account the processings after and before. But indeed, if a more "conventional" design is possible, it is always better to avoid this sort of thing unless you want to use the great *flow-control by exceptions* pattern. In the example here, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Downvoting because this is not an appropriate use of `throw new Exception`.